# Azure Fluent Management API: Remove an app setting

Tags: azure, azure-fluent-api

I'm trying to remove  the AzureWebJobsDashboard app setting from a Function App which is provisioned using the [fluent management API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/)

```
    var fnApp = await azure.AppServices.FunctionApps
         .Define("fnappname")
         .WithExistingAppServicePlan(fnAppPlan)
         .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
         .WithExistingStorageAccount(fnStorage)
         .WithRuntimeVersion("~2")
         .WithHttp20Enabled(true)
         .WithAppSetting("AzureWebJobsDashboard", null)
         .WithTags(tags)
         .CreateAsync();
```

I've tried setting the app setting to null and also to an empty string, but it seems to make no difference and I don't see a method to explicitly delete a setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WithoutAppSetting("AzureWebJobsDashboard")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.webappbase.update.iwithappsettings-1.withoutappsetting?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_AppService_Fluent_WebAppBase_Update_IWithAppSettings_1_WithoutAppSetting_System_String_).